# transition for addclass only works after first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I basically have some social media icons at the top of the page, that later become fixed.

I want them to fade in, I was using CSS. Everything I tried using JS did the same thing or didn't work.

Here is my JS:

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = jQuery(document).scrollTop(), //get page y value
            social = jQuery(".socialnetworks"),
            headerHeight = jQuery(".bg-cover").height();
        if(y >= headerHeight + 500)  {
            social.css({opacity : 0});
            social.addClass("fixedsocialnetworks");
        } else {
          social.removeClass("fixedsocialnetworks");
        }

});
```

And my CSS

```
.fixedsocialnetworks {
    position: fixed!important;
    top: 200px!important;
    z-index:10;
    left:30px;
    opacity:1!important;
     transition: opacity 400ms;
}
```

So I set the opacity to 0, then add a class that sets the opacity to 1, and has the transition.

So it works, but it doesn't work the first time on scroll, it works every other time after the first. Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: try removing the `social.css({opacity : 0});` line and adding this as CSS `.socialnetworks { opacity: 0; }`

Comment: @MichaelCoker but I don't want it's opacity to be 0 all the time, because it does display at other points in time (aka not fixed)

Comment: can you add the html/css/js to a snippet so we have a working demo?

Comment: Why not just use keyframe animations?  This doesn't address why your code is retaining the `opacity: 0`, but if all you want is for it to transition in every time you add that class, it might be a better approach: https://jsfiddle.net/k9t97ptc/

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it @JosephMarikle